# Path reconstruction from accelerometer and gyroscope data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, data-analysis, sensor

I found a dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/malekzadeh/motionsense-dataset?resource=download) whose columns are

- attitude.roll, attitude.pitch, attitude.yaw
- gravity.x, gravity.y, gravity.z
- rotationRate.x, rotationRate.y, rotationRate.z
- acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z

The corresponding rows contain numbers collected by a sensor placed on the shoes of people moving. Each row represents data collected by the sensor at time $t_i = t_0 + i(\delta t)$, starting from an initial time $t_0$ with a constant and known time interval $\delta t$.

I suppose that each sensor "has" its own internal orthonormal and right-handed reference frame $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$.

My question is to find a formula that gives the position of the sensor at every time $t_i$ w.r.t. to a fixed external orthonormal and right-handed reference frame $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}, \tilde{z}$ whose origin is the initial position of the sensor at $t_0$ and whose orientation coincides precisely with $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$.

Towards a formalization of the setup consider two series of vectors
$$ 
T_i = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_i \\
\beta_i \\
\gamma_i
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
A_i = \begin{pmatrix}
a_i \\
b_i \\
c_i
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
i = 0, \ldots, n
$$
where

- each $T_i$ represents an intrinsic rotation whose Tait–Bryan angles are $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$, $\gamma_i$, that is a linear transformation represented by the matrix
  \begin{align}
    R_i &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \cos \alpha_i & -\sin \alpha_i & 0 \\
      \sin \alpha_i &  \cos \alpha_i & 0 \\
                0 &            0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
       \cos \beta_i & 0 & \sin \beta_i \\
                0 & 1 &          0 \\
      -\sin \beta_i & 0 & \cos \beta_i \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 &  0          &            0 \\
      0 & \cos \gamma_i & -\sin \gamma_i \\
      0 & \sin \gamma_i &  \cos \gamma_i \\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
  with respect to the right-handed system $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$. This should match with the columns attitude.roll, attitude.pitch, attitude.yaw
- each $A_i$ vector components represent one component of acceleration w.r.t. one coordinate axis: $a_i$ is the $x$-component, $b_i$ is the $y$-component and $c_i$ is the $z$-component. This should match with the columns acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z

Can the formula I want be derived with just attitude and acceleration data. How The other sensor data need to be accounted for, if so?

Comment: you can try this $\begin{aligned}\overrightarrow{v}=\int R\overrightarrow{A}dt\\
\overrightarrow{p}=\int \overrightarrow{v}dt\end{aligned}$

Comment: position can be found just by double integrating acceleration per time slice. Given location at time=0, accel x, accel y, accel z data alone is in principle enough to find the 3D position of the person at any given time. I have read that this position found by double integration is not very accurate, though, thus gyroscope data (rot x, rot y, rot z) is used to increase precision. To my knowledge, grav x, grav y, grav z are derived quantities from the raw accelerometer data, and yaw, pitch, roll are derived quantities from the raw gyroscope data.

Comment: I think the acceleration is measured in body fixed system, not in inertial system, and the transformation matrix must be a function of the roll, pitch and yaw angles

Comment: @Eli i guess the reference system might not matter in the end, as the accelerometer measures direct pressure on a spring in the x, y, z direction, which signifies acceleration in that direction (https://www.explainthatstuff.com/accelerometers.html)

Comment: @James do rotationRate.x, rotationRate.y, rotationRate.z might play a role in the computation ?

Comment: @AlbertoCarraro I have not done it myself, but i think rotx, roty, rotz might be used to double check the new position relative to old position after using accel x, accel y, accel z... check if the rotation generated by accelerometer agrees with those independently measured by gyroscope... If they differ, we might choose to average them, or favor one instrument over the other, etc..